# const pointer in for loop (C++ 11)

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

Can someone explain why it is possible to declare a *const* pointer to something that has a different value for each iteration of the loop?

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
...

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const aiVector3D* vp = &(mesh->mVertices[i]);
    // use vp.x ...
}
```

This snippet is part of an example code of how to use assimp to import mesh-data. (i am new to c++)

Comment: `const` just means that the compiler will not allow *you* to change the value. `int i = 0; const int * p = &i; ++(*p) /* error */; ++i /* ok */;`

Comment: I think there's also a misconception about what `const aiVector3D* vp` means vs. `aiVector3D* const vp`.

Comment: Right, in the example, it's NOT a const pointer; it's a pointer to a const object.  There is a big difference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Answer (score 2):

Its because `vp` gets destroyed and redeclared every iteration. It's not that it's pointing to a different variable each time, it's a completely different pointer.

Comment: it doesn't invalidate the answer.

Comment: in order to extract a value but not alter it in any way, or because the API he uses obligates him to pass const pointer , or many other reasons for why use `const` in C++

Comment: @ultralord Because it expresses the intent of the programmer and prevents mistakes. By declaraing `vp` as `const`, you're indicating that you only need to read its value within the body of the for-loop, and the compiler will complain if you accidentally attempt to do otherwise.

Comment: No, this answer is incorrect.  It's NOT a const pointer.  It's a non-const pointer to a const object.  The same non-const pointer can be modified to point to a different const object.